# Scrolling overflow on fixed element on iPhone/Android

Tags: jquery, ios, css, drop-down-menu, responsive-design

I am in the process of building a responsive site: http://test.spuddmobile.com/

I am having issues with the menu. If you view the site on a mobile device in portrait, click the menu button then switch to landscape, you cannot scroll the menu. But if you open the menu in landscape scrolling works fine (although it doesn't quite scroll far enough and should end further than the end of the red phone button).

I am just wondering if anyone else has experienced anything similar this and/or has a fix?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a project I was contacted about back in April.  Small world!

Tested this for you on a couple of iPhones and the simulator in XCode, I can't replicate the bug at all?

Do bear in mind that using `position: absolute` for elements of this nature can cause inherent problems when positioned off the top of the page because - by their nature - they will always be positioned off the top of the window and therefore, if taller than the viewport, you can't access anything off the bottom.

The easiest away around this is to ensure that you're positioning off a scrollable element on your page (ie: `#page_content`) so that it 'sticks' to the top of that rather than to the window.  This will require some considerable rewriting of your markup though so perhaps not the best option.

Alternatively, consider putting the content you want to scroll inside a further element with a fixed height.  That way, your mobile users swipe up/down on the panel.  Bear in mind that this could potentially look ugly if a desktop browser happens to be viewing the site at the same width though since scroll bars will be displayed.

Comment: Small world indeed. Thanks for your response. I managed to fix this problem by making the menu wrapper expand to the height of the screen on orientation change with jQuery.